# How to solve, No module named 'tf'?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I tried to convert my CNN model .h5 file to a .tflite file using this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.lite import TFLiteConverter

converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('/drive/My Drive/FSD_modelV09A.h5')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("/drive/My Drive/FSD_modelV09A.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

But then there's an error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'
```

Comment: use `from tensorflow.lite import TFLiteConverter`.

Comment: This is because when you write `tf.lite`. Python searches for `tf` instead of `tensorflow`. Even when `tensorflow` is imported as `tf`.

Comment: I tried to import with the full module name, but then this error happened: 

`ImportError: cannot import name 'TFLiteConverter'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot make imports from module aliases, you have to use the full module name:

```
from tensorflow.lite import TFLiteConverter
```

You can also just refer to `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter` in code

Comment: I tried to import with the full module name, but then this error happened:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'TFLiteConverter'`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `tensorflow` module is not fully loaded (yet) when you try to make other imports. E.g. when you do `from X import Y`, aliases are not known yet, so `X` cannot be an alias. Try importing from the original module name:

```py
from tensorflow.lite import TFLiteConverter
```